# Trying to string.Join an IList

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, interface

I'm trying to implement the first example http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-string into my method but I'm having a hard time matching the 2nd argument for the method:

```
string printitout = string.Join(",", test.ToArray<Location>);
```

error message:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string,
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>)' has some invalid arguments
```

All the IList interfaces are implemented with the IEnurmerable too (just not listed here unless someone wants me to).

```
class IList2
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

     string sSite = "test";
     string sSite1 = "test";
     string sSite2 = "test";

     Locations test = new Locations();
     Location loc = new Location();
     test.Add(sSite)
     test.Add(sSite1)
     test.Add(sSite2)
     string printitout = string.Join(",", test.ToArray<Location>); //having issues calling what it needs.

     }
 }
string printitout = string.Join(",", test.ToArray<Location>);


public class Location
{
    public Location()
    {

    }
    private string _site = string.Empty;
    public string Site
    {
        get { return _site; }
        set { _site = value; }
    }
}

public class Locations : IList<Location>
{
    List<Location> _locs = new List<Location>();

    public Locations() { }

    public void Add(string sSite)
    {
        Location loc = new Location();
        loc.Site = sSite;
        _locs.Add(loc);
    }
 }
```

Edit:
Ok using "string.Join(",", test);"  works, before I close this with a check mark, for some reason my output, outputs:

"Ilistprac.Location, Ilistprac.Location, Ilistprac.Location"

for some reason instead of what's in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `ToArray()` at all (since it appears you're using .Net 4.0) so you can make the call

```
string.Join(",", test);
```

Comment: Just before I answered this good. My output outputs as: "Ilistprac.Location, Ilistprac.Location, Ilistprac.Location" and not the list items in the list for some reason.

Comment: You haven't overriden `ToString()` on your `Location` objects, so you are getting the default behavior.

Comment: @dlev - What does that mean haven't overridden ToString() on objects?  The answer does not say anything about overriding ToString().  How do you fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put parentheses - `()` - after `ToArray<Location>`:

```
string printitout = string.Join(",", test.Select(location => location.Site).ToArray());
```

Comment: ah lambda, I'm not good with that but I'm trying to learn it! That actually outputs whats in the IList correctly too.

Answer (score 2):

If your `Locaions` type implements `IEnumerable` you won't need `ToArray`:

```
string printiout = String.Join(",", test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string printitout = string.Join(",", test);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get this Error Message: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'string.Join<Ilistprac.Location>(string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Ilistprac.Location>)' and 'string.Join(string, params object[])'